# Return an array with LINQ to SQL query

Tags: c#, sql, linq, wcf, windows-phone-8

I want to return an array to my WP 8 page and have an error: `not all code paths return a value`. How can I correct it? 
My WCF service has the following code:

```
public Point getAllusrs (int myID)
    {
        DataClasses1DataContext data = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        var a = (from s in data.Tabs where s.u1ID == myID && s.status == true select s.u2ID).ToArray();
        int inc = 0;

        foreach (var d in data.Users)
        {
            if (a[inc] != null && d.Id == a[inc])
            {
                inc++;
                return new Point() { Lat = d.usrLat, Lon = d.usrLong };
            }
            else inc++;
        }       
    }
```

Comment: Do you actually want to return an array of `Point` or a single `Point`?

Comment: @Dave, array of `Point` to create multiple pushpins on the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must handle the case, when there is no user with target `Id`.

For example, you can return default value in the end of the method:

```
public Point getAllusrs (int myID)
{
    DataClasses1DataContext data = new DataClasses1DataContext();
    var a = (from s in data.Tabs where s.u1ID == myID && s.status == true select s.u2ID).ToArray();
    int inc = 0;

    foreach (var d in data.Users)
    {
        if (a[inc] != null && d.Id == a[inc])
        {
            inc++;
            return new Point() { Lat = d.usrLat, Lon = d.usrLong };
        }
        else inc++;
    }       
    return default(Point); // or some Point with default Lat and Lon
}
```

or throw some exception:

```
public Point getAllusrs (int myID)
{
    DataClasses1DataContext data = new DataClasses1DataContext();
    var a = (from s in data.Tabs where s.u1ID == myID && s.status == true select s.u2ID).ToArray();
    int inc = 0;

    foreach (var d in data.Users)
    {
        if (a[inc] != null && d.Id == a[inc])
        {
            inc++;
            return new Point() { Lat = d.usrLat, Lon = d.usrLong };
        }
        else inc++;
    }       
    throw new Exception("Point not found"); // or some custom Exception
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because if the code doesn't satisfy the condition it doesn't return any value.

```
public Point getAllusrs (int myID)
{
    Point pnt = null; // or new Point ();
    DataClasses1DataContext data = new DataClasses1DataContext();
    var a = (from s in data.Tabs where s.u1ID == myID && s.status == true select s.u2ID).ToArray();
    int inc = 0;

    foreach (var d in data.Users)
    {
        if (a[inc] != null && d.Id == a[inc])
        {
            inc++;
            pnt = new Point() { Lat = d.usrLat, Lon = d.usrLong };
        }
        else inc++;
    }  

    return pnt;   
}
```